# ITaskScheduler and the IClientSecurity interface

Tags: c++, security, com, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to somehow obtain an IClientSecurity pointer from the ITaskScheduler interface? I need to call CoSetProxyBlanket on ITaskScheduler, as I am calling it's ITaskScheduler methods from a COM+ object that is instantiated in classic ASP pages (by authorized users only). However querying for IClientSecurity returns a 'not implemented' error. Is it possible to load a proxy for ITaskScheduler? Currently I can't call the ITaskScheduler methods without getting 'access denied' errors.

Comment: Are you running the classic ASP configured to impersonate the calling user? That's probably the simplest way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Some time ago I tried adding logic in the COM object which called LogonUser, DuplicateToken and then ImpersonateLoggedOnUser. However even though this ran successfully I still got access denied errors when attempting to call any ITaskScheduler methods on Windows Server 2003 (everything runs fine without any impersonation logic on Windows XP). The appropriate settings were made for the COM+ application too.

Comment: You just configure to use "integrated authentication" and set the option to impersonate the logged-on user. Then, when they access the webpage, they get the standard browser login box. They enter their username/password and they are logged on, and the web app has their permissions. You don't have to call LogonUser.